# Is there any way to set the maximum duration of a Tropo call?

Tags: php, voip, tropo

According to the online documentation, Tropo calls are limited to 2 hours. Is there any way to change that value? In other words, is there any way to set the maximum duration of a Tropo call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No timelimits on outbound calls are currently not supported in Tropo.
More information in their support forum: https://www.tropo.com/account/tickets/tickets.jsp?bb-cid=94&bb-tid=1285258&bb-name=tropo_support

Comment: But you can use other platform like asterisk hosted on amazon ec2, it support features you need.